# Insertar datos con props react

Tags: reactjs

Con useState guardo el valor inicial y con la funcion `guardarDireccion` cambio el estado con el valor que el usuario escribe en el textfield, pero mi campo usuario no lo van ingresar los usuarios, traigo el valor desde los props de esta forma `(props,access).user` y cambio su estado de esta forma  `setDireccion({...direccion,usuario: (props,access).user })` en el handleSubmit pero al momento de ingresar los datos el campo usuario me aparece en blanco. Ya comprobe con `console.log` que si manda el nombre de usuario a traves de los props.

¿Cual podria ser el el problema?

```
import React, { useState}  from 'react';
import  axios  from 'axios';
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

function AgregarDirecciones(props) {

    const url='/addDirecciones';

    const initialState = { estado: '',  ciudad: '', codigo_postal:0, usuario:'' }

    const [direccion, setDireccion] = useState(initialState) 

    function GuardarDireccion(event) { 
      setDireccion({...direccion, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();  
        setDireccion({...direccion,usuario: props.access.user })
            async function agregarDireccion() {
                await axios.post(url, direccion); 
                }
                agregarDireccion();
      }

    return ( 
      <div > 
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
        name="estado"
        label="Estado"
        value={direccion.estado}
        onChange={GuardarDireccion}
        margin="normal"
      />
     <TextField
        name="ciudad"
        label="Ciudad"
        value={direccion.ciudad}
        onChange={GuardarDireccion}
        margin="normal"
    />
    <TextField
        name="codigo_postal"
        label="Codigo postal"
        value={direccion.codigo_postal}
        onChange={GuardarDireccion}
        margin="normal"
    />
          <Button
              variant="contained"
              type="submit">
                    Guardar
          </Button>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Pordrias agregar el error que te sale, o no obtienes ninguno?

Comment: @Shassain no obtengo ningun error

Comment: podrias compartir tu componente completo?  para tener un mejor contexto a tu duda? ademas si `access` es un objeto, los parentesis estan de mas, `props.access.user` o `const { user } = props.access`

Comment: @Isaac claro ya edite la pregunta